# Angular Error ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, accordion, angular-ng-if

Angular Js returning me this error link

```
 [1]http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%2013-14%20%5B'%5D&p2=recipe.ID%20!%3D%3D'
```

I dont know how to apply the solution. Please help me. 
Thanks
My javascript :

```
var app = angular.module('sample', [])

app.directive("otcDynamic", function ($compile) {// compile Json data return and wrap inside html
    return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
        var template = global.userhtml;
        var linkFn = $compile(template);
        var content = linkFn(scope);
        element.append(content);
     }
   }
});
```

Json Data Return from web api

```
var global {
userhtml ='<table class="recipe-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr class="recipe-list" data-ng-repeat="recipe in recipe_data" ng-if="recipe.Keyword == keyw.Keyword" ><td  id="td-img{{recipe.CodeListe}}" rowspan="2"><center><span id="img{{recipe.ID}}X"><a id="{{recipe.ID}}" href="javascript:void(0);"> <img  ng-if="recipe.ID !==''" fallback-src="images/default.png" ng-src="{{recipe.Pictures}}" class="images" id="img{{recipe.ID}}"/><img  ng-if="recipe.Pictures===''" class="images" src="images/default.png" id="img1"/></a></span></center></td><td class="recipes"><div id="drn" class="div-recipe-name"><strong>{{recipe.Name}}</strong></div><br /><div id="drd" class="div-recipe-desc">{{recipe.desc}}</div><div class="div-recipe-allergen">{{recipe.allergen}}</div><div class="div-recipe-cost">{{recipe.cost}}</div></td></tr></tbody></table>' 
}
```

My Html :

```
  <accordion close-others="false">
  <div>
    <accordion-group class="div-recipe-header">
      <accordion-heading></accordion-heading>
        <my-directive></my-directive>
          <div otc-dynamic></div>   
    </accordion-group>
  </div>
</accordion>
```

Comment: That data returned from your web API isn't valid JSON. It isn't even valid Javascript.

Comment: Actually it compile succesfully but not on the part of ng-if recipe ID and recipe.Pictures . I know I have to put backslash in order Json can read that. But I cannot insert data with backslash in sql server. Help me How Can I made my json valid..

Comment: If it compiles then that can't be the actual data returned by your API. As I said that isn't even valid Javascript.

Comment: @winterblood The Angular $compile function takes an HTML string, which is exactly what he is giving it from the 'userhtml' variable. The problem is probably caused by the fact that his HTML string is surrounded by single-quotes yet also seems to try to contain unescaped single-quotes inside it...

Answer (score 0):

Your web api should return something like this:

```
{ 
  global: {
    userhtml: 'your html code in a string' 
  }
}
```

But notice that you have other ways (better ones) to do this. You can receive a pure json data and render it using html templates.

One more thing: `global` is reserved word in a lot of languages and frameworks, and it's not a good name for variable or hash key. Consider changing it for anything more apropriate.